# Booting and shutting down process is very slow, with some others issues

Tags: 12.04

Recently I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 replacing Ubuntu 11.10, after installation, When I started my "Lenovo W520", I  feel uncomfortable. It is  too slow in booting process and also very slow in shutting down. Some operations are very slow.

The booting is so slow that, it's seems It is a Windows system instead of an Ubuntu.

Can anyone suggest, what actions  I can take to investigate the issue and then to fix the problem? Re-installation advice should be last option.

Comment: I'd start with the system monitor and see if there are any run-away processes eating up system resources.  Then after that, maybe run a surface scan on the disk to make sure there isnt an issue with the hdd.

Comment: unfortunately no one's you suggest resolve my issue... thanks

Comment: Have you tried switching to 2d to see if its an accelerator problem?

Comment: Did you install the Graphics driver properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed from disk, perhaps you changed the boot priority sequence from harddrive to disk/usb, but neglected to revert to the original settings, in which case a few seconds would be wasted as the computer works through the boot media precedence list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem on a Dell Inspiron 6400 with 2Gb Ram and Pentium dual Core 1.86GHz processor. I switched to Unity 2D and till now it looks faster.